# Search Results Web results Is there a way to post Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking (Measuring Purchases) to Google Analytics via server-side

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

Is it possible to post Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking (measuring purchases) to [Google analytic Ecommerce overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXms.png) and to be show in the graph??

I tried to make it work in [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFAhy.png) but it's not working, please advise

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Try to use **[Hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)** instead Postman. This tools allows you to construct and validate Measurement Protocol hits using the Measurement Protocol Validation Server.

Answer (score 0):

UPdate:

It works, just took few hours to reflect on google analytics, remember to change your `transaction ID` each time you run the post request!